# Nu Html Checker detects empty <title></title> tag - but it doesn't seem empty

Tags: html

Trying to get my wife's page to comply with HTML5, I submitted it to the Nu Html Checker, and after a few first corrections insists I have an empty  element:

```
Error: Element title must not be empty.
From line 5, column 12; to line 5, column 19
   <title></title>↩    <
```

Now, if I download the page in Firefox, and show the source, I find:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Asociación Cordobesa de Farmacéuticos</title>
    <style>
      body {background-image="imagenes/acfahbg1.jpg"}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
```

So, the title does not seem to be empty...

Comment: Based on what you have provided here I am unable to replicate your error. Pasting your HTML into the Nu HTML Checker does not produce any errors for me. This leads me to believe there is something else outside of what is shown here that would be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are downloading the correct html page. Also, in Firefox and in other browsers, you can directly view source code of the web page - when you right-click the page, and select "View Page Source". If I really found your wife's page here https://www.acfah.org/ then the title really is empty (I can see it in the "view source". Also the title of Firefox tab shows only url, not title.)